# What is the idiomatic way to capture prints to *out* from a Clojure function?

Tags: clojure, stdout

For example, the **[prxml](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/prxml-api.html)** function prints XML to *out*. I would like to instead capture this output as a String. Here is the typical usage from a REPL:

```
user> (prxml [:p "Test"])
<p>Test</p>nil
```

I'd instead like to do:

```
(def xml (capture-out (prxml [:p "Test"])))
```

I made up the **capture-out** function, but I suspect something like it exists, only I'm having trouble finding it in the [API](http://clojure.org/api) or mailing list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just discovered the **with-out-str** from this [great blog post](http://nakkaya.com/2009/10/10/processing-xml-with-clojure/) detailing XML processing in Clojure.

So the correct implementation of my example is:

```
(def xml (with-out-str (prxml [:p "Test"])))
```

Answer (score 6):

More generally, if you look at the source for `with-out-str` you can see how to dynamically bind `*out*` to any stream using `binding`.  This works for dynamically setting the value of any existing var.